# Is there a way to only require password on waking from sleep and not on screensaver (In Snow Leopard)?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

I hate it when it asks me for password when I'm at home getting away from a computer for a while. I do like it having a screensaver though.
But for some reason I see that password settings for the screensaver is merged with the password settings for waking from sleep. And waking password is an essential security feature for me. Essentially when Im not in a secured environment I close the lid when going away from the laptop even for a minute, but at home I want it to stay open.

Is there a way to have it ask for password only after sleep and not after screensaver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [SleepWatcher](http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/macosx/17579)

Follow the instructions for installation and configuration. Create a shell script with the following command, and use SleepWatcher to execute it upon sleep:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend
```

Comment: this might work, but a little to much manual labor for a simple task :)

Comment: Alas, sometimes to customize parts of the operating system to perform a simple task, it requires a little labour. :)

Answer (score 1):

From http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=230074

Enable 'Require password ...' in Security panel General tab.

Then paste this in Terminal:

```
defaults -currentHost write com.apple.screensaver askForPassword -int 0
```

To undo:

```
defaults -currentHost write com.apple.screensaver askForPassword -int 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always disable your screensaver so that it never activates.